# appendRow() and deleteRow() from multiple users at the same time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, locking

I have one backend function to append new rows to a Google Sheet and a lock service is used to prevent the conflicts of multiple users.

```
sh.appendRow(record);
```

Another backend function is to delete rows from the same sheet and a lock service is used as well.

```
sh.deleteRow(posIndex+2)
```

While I have concern that one user is appending a row at the same time as another user is deleting a row, will it cause any trouble? Since the lock service is used independently in these two functions, they will not lock each other.

Answer (score 1):

The Lock Service has three scopes,

- User
- Document
- Script

Using the the document scope is very likely to be the best option. For this use [getDocumentLock()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getDocumentLock()).

Related

- [How to understand LockService and implement it correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43223774/1595451)
- [How to check if a function in Google App Script is already being executed by another user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45816748/1595451)

Comment: This is a standalone script and my understanding is the document lock is for the script in the google sheet. Is that correct? Thank you.